# Generating partial classes using source generator removes original class

Tags: c#, code-generation, dynamically-generated, c#-9.0

So I'm experimenting with the new `ISourceGenerator` system to generate a few I18n strings & classes from XML files. This works but now I want to extend an existing partial class using a source generator, but whenever I do the original class contents become inaccessible! This is the class I have:

```
// File: Strings.cs
namespace MyProject.I18n
{
    public static partial class Strings
    {
        public const string Options = "Options";
    }
}
```

This is what I'm generating:

```
// Generated file: GeneratedStrings.cs
namespace MyProject.I18n
{
    public static partial class Strings
    {
        public const string MainMenu = "Main menu";
    }
}
```

This is how I'm generating it (MVCE):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

[Generator]
public class I18NGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private const string XML_EXAMPLE = @"
<Strings>
    <MainMenu>Main menu</MainMenu>
</Strings>
";

    private StringBuilder sb = null!;
    private int indentation;

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        indentation = 0;
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var root = XDocument.Parse(XML_EXAMPLE).Root!;

        void Process(XElement element)
        {
            var text = element.Nodes().FirstOrDefault(node => node is XText);
            if (text is XText xText)
            {
                IndentedLn($@"public static string {element.Name.LocalName} = ""{xText.Value}"";");
            }
            else
            {
                BeginBlock($"public static partial class {element.Name.LocalName}");
                foreach (var xElement in element.Elements())
                    Process(xElement);
                EndBlock();
            }
        }

        BeginBlock("namespace MyProject.I18n");
        Process(root);
        EndBlock();
        context.AddSource("GeneratedStrings.cs", SourceText.From(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }

    private void Indent()
    {
        indentation++;
    }

    private void Dedent()
    {
        indentation--;
    }

    private void BeginBlock(string statement = "")
    {
        if (statement.Length != 0)
            IndentedLn(statement);
        IndentedLn("{");
        Indent();
    }

    private void EndBlock()
    {
        Dedent();
        IndentedLn("}");
    }

    private void Raw(string text) => sb.Append(text);

    private void Indented(string code)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < indentation; i++)
            Raw("\t");
        Raw(code);
    }

    private void IndentedLn(string code) => Indented(code + "\n");
}
```

Trying to access `Strings.Options` gives the compilation error `'Strings' does not contain a definition for 'Options'`.

I can add that if I generate BOTH files they merge just fine.

Comment: Did you try doing the same thing with a non static partial class? Does it give the problem with non static class too?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No difference unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS and deleting .vs?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Yes, I even tried a whole different IDE!